# d3 getting array of keys from data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a grouped chart that can toggle its series on and off - here is a working demo

https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/64a6c1892d1893009d2b99b8abee75a7

and I am trying to get it work from a json input - but I am running into errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/231/

I essentially want to obtain the key array from the data.

var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
^ this used to be in place when it was a csv

so need to obtain this key

```
var keys = [
"AA",
"BB"
]
```

from the data

```
var data = [{
"State": "CA",
"AA": 100,
"BB": 200
},
{
"State": "TX",
"AA": 454,
"BB": 344
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no `columns` property created by `d3.json`, you can get the keys using `d3.keys`:

```
var keys = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [{
  "State": "CA",
  "AA": 100,
  "BB": 200
}, {
  "State": "TX",
  "AA": 454,
  "BB": 344
}];

var keys = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);

console.log(keys)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As the order of the keys is undefined, a safer approach would be dropping that `slice` and using `filter` instead:

```js
var data = [{
  "State": "CA",
  "AA": 100,
  "BB": 200
}, {
  "State": "TX",
  "AA": 454,
  "BB": 344
}];


var keys = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) {
  return d != "State";
});
console.log(keys)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Object.keys()

Comment: "var keys = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);" - I think its keeping it to a d3 base

Comment: Unlike `Object.keys()`, `d3.keys` does a very basic `for...in` loop. Also, please do not use the answer space for questions or comments: use the *add a comment* option below the answer/question.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - so do you think Object.keys() should be used instead?

Comment: @TheOldCounty it doesn't matter, the result will be the same.

Comment: Sure - @GerardoFurtado - some have philosophical reasons -- I have a bounty on a line chart that is similar -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700389/d3-js-curved-line-charts-with-toggle-legends

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it was stated as a question, but it was still an answer. Adjusted so its a statement rather than a question though, you're right